# Screen scraping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping

I'm trying to build a client side screen scraping.

I want to allow in browser browsing (using a frame), and let the user mark an area he wants to grab and save on his board.

Is there a good JavaScript solution for such requirement?

Comment: what do you want to grab, the HTML content? or the Screen Shot ? Please Specify.

Comment: If the content that you're scraping isn't on your domain, you can't touch it with JavaScript. Not even in an `<iframe>`.

Comment: Take a screenshot programatically, show them the image, and let them select where to crop?

Comment: How do I take a screen shot?

Comment: you can use phantomjs, just like Ishan's answer alludes to. But, you need to communicate with your server, and you can't see the users browser window - they need to provide the url to load into your server and render.

Comment: I don't see how that answers my requirements. I also thought about Web-Proxy, but I couldn't find a way to do it without trashing some of the websites and some even block such proxy.

Comment: Do you want to obtain the content from the same domain, or from an external domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Node.js for web scraping.

This is a [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/web-scraping-with-node-js/) where you can learn how to use it.

Comment: Negative rater care to comment please?

Comment: But, that is server side, how can I use it present the user a way to scrap part of his view?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a screenshot of the current page and draw it on an HTML canvas, then you can use [HTMLToCanvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). This won't work for external sites, though: it can only take a screenshot of the currently loaded page.

Using the [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture), web pages can record screenshots of any window on the user's desktop.